# Jquery Slideshow load random random image order

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, slideshow

I have a simple Jquery slideshow, that fades a list of images one after the other.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(3000)
     .next('img').fadeIn(3000)
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
  3000);
});
</script>
```

What I want to do now is to make them randomized. As this slideshow is in the header of  my page, every time a user navigates to a different page the slideshow starts from the beginning again.

I want to make it so that the images show in random order.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you give a little more information on the HTML for the slideshow?

Answer (score 0):

try with this logic

```
<body onload="document.body.background = '/images/img'+Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+'.jpg';" />
```

or try with this function

```
$.fn.randomImage = function (){
var $imageNumber = 8, 
// Set the amount of images in the Sprite
$height = $('> div', this).innerHeight(),
$random_num = Math.random() * $imageNumber - 1,
$multiple = Math.round($random_num),
$random = $height * $multiple
jQuery('.image').css( 
{'background-position' : '0px -' + $random + 'px',  'display' : 'block' } 
)};
```

and then

```
jQuery('#image-container').randomImage();
```

Reference

[random images](http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/simple_two_line_image_randomiser_script_with_jquery)
[another](http://iantearle.com/blog/jquery-random-image-selector)

Comment: one more reference : http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1089802.html

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin I found at http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/jquery.shuffle.js
 might do the trick. It shuffles all the elements selected. There's also a demo here: http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/shuffle/demo.html.

Usage is like `$('#imagediv').shuffle();`